# Align divs horizontally with rails generated loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, horizontallistview

I'm trying to lay out a list of blog posts horizontally. But I don't know how. I was able to achieve the result i wanted using css flexbox when creating the static mockup, but as soon as I replace the placeholder tags with rails loop, the layout breaks and all posts line up vertically. Also, Below the end of the last post, theres this string of texts with all the posts information floating at the bottom(see attached photo), not sure what i did wrong here.  [image: strings at the bottom of the post]

Below are my html and css setup:

```
  <section id="posts" class="wrapper">
    <h2>My Latest Articles</h2>
    <hr>

    <div class="post_container">
      <div class="article">
        <%= @posts.each do |p| %>
        <h3 class="post_title"><%= link_to p.title, p %></h3>
        <p class="post_date"><%= p.created_at.strftime("%A,%b %d") %></p>
        <p class="content"><%= truncate(p.content, length: 400)  %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#posts {
    padding: 6.5em 0 10em 0;
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: $text;
        margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    }

    .post_container {
        padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
        .article {
            max-width: 28%;
        }
        .post_title {
            color: $text;
      font-size: 1.6em;
        }
        .post_date {
            padding: .75rem 0;
            color: $accent;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }
        .content {
            color: $grey;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried applying `display: flex` to the `.article` div? Since flex items are always the children of a flex container, that would seem to make sense.

Comment: Hey thx for the reply. Yes I figured out the problem now, It looks like I should've included the `.article` div inside the loop, and that fixed the problem! However, I still have that texts showing up at the end..um.

Comment: @YorkWang check my answer to remove the long text at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the string of information below the posts, you need to modify your erb code.

Change the `post_container` div to this:

```
<div class="post_container">
  <div class="article">
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>
      <h3 class="post_title"><%= link_to p.title, p %></h3>
      <p class="post_date"><%= p.created_at.strftime("%A,%b %d") %></p>
      <p class="content"><%= truncate(p.content, length: 400)  %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked! I accidentally output the .each now i fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding everything inside the loop with a div. Hope this helps!